# Understanding a step in Rudin's proof of the Inverse Function Theorem

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

I am reading Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis", and in a step for the proof on the inverse function theorem he says that the derivative of:

$\phi(x)=x+A^{-1}(y-f(x))$

is

$\phi'(x)=I-A^{-1}f'(x)$

Where $A=f'(a)$ and $a$ is a vector in $\mathbb R^n$ (as are $x$ and $y$).

I read on some online sources that this derivative uses the chain rule, although I am not sure how. Could somebody walk me through the steps on how this derivative was computed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simplicity, let us consider $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$. Then we see that $\phi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by
\begin{align}
\phi(x_1, x_2) =&\ 
\begin{pmatrix}
\phi_1(x_1, x_2)\\
\phi_2(x_1, x_2)
\end{pmatrix}\\
=&\ 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{1, x_1} (a_1, a_2) & f_{1, x_2}(a_1, a_2)\\
f_{2, x_1} (a_1, a_2) & f_{2, x_2}(a_1, a_2)
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
\left(
\begin{pmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2
\end{pmatrix}
+
\begin{pmatrix}
f_1(x_1, x_2)\\
f_2(x_1, x_2)
\end{pmatrix}
 \right)\\
=&\ \begin{pmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2
\end{pmatrix}+ \frac{1}{\det Df(a)}\begin{pmatrix}
f_{2, x_2} (a_1, a_2)f_1(x_1, x_2) -f_{1, x_2}(a_1, a_2)f_2(x_1, x_2)\\
-f_{2, x_1} (a_1, a_2)f_1(x_1, x_2)+  f_{1, x_1}(a_1, a_2)f_2(x_1, x_2)
\end{pmatrix}
+\text{ const vector}
\end{align}

Then we see that
\begin{align}
\nabla\phi(x_1, x_2) =&\ 
\begin{pmatrix}
\phi_{1, x_1} & \phi_{1, x_2}\\
\phi_{2, x_1} & \phi_{2, x_2}
\end{pmatrix}\\
=&\ 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
+\frac{1}{\det Df(a)}
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{2, x_2} (a_1, a_2)f_{1, x_1}(x_1, x_2) -f_{1, x_2}(a_1, a_2)f_{2, x_1}(x_1, x_2) & f_{2, x_2} (a_1, a_2)f_{1, x_2}(x_1, x_2) -f_{1, x_2}(a_1, a_2)f_{2, x_2}(x_1, x_2) \\
-f_{2, x_1} (a_1, a_2)f_{1, x_1}(x_1, x_2)+  f_{1, x_1}(a_1, a_2)f_{2, x_1}(x_1, x_2) & -f_{2, x_1} (a_1, a_2)f_{1, x_2}(x_1, x_2)+  f_{1, x_1}(a_1, a_2)f_{2, x_2}(x_1, x_2)
\end{pmatrix}\\
=&\ 
\begin{pmatrix}
1  & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
+\frac{1}{\det Df(a)}\begin{pmatrix}
f_{2, x_2} (a_1, a_2)& -f_{1, x_2}(a_1, a_2)\\
-f_{2, x_1} (a_1, a_2)&  f_{1, x_1}(a_1, a_2)
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
f_{1, x_1} (x_1, x_2)& f_{1, x_2}(x_1, x_2)\\
f_{2, x_1} (x_1, x_2)&  f_{2, x_2}(x_1, x_2)
\end{pmatrix}\\
=&\ I+Df(a_1, a_2)^{-1} Df(x_1, x_2).
\end{align}

**Higher Dimension:**

However, when $n$ is large, the above way of expanding everything out then taking partial derivatives is messy. Hence we need to compute the derivative in a more elegant manner.

In general, we see that
\begin{align}
D_x \phi(x) =&\ D_x x+ D_x [A^{-1}(y-f(x))]\\
=&\ I+ D_x[A^{-1}]\circ D_x[y-f(x)]\\
=&\ I+ A^{-1}\circ(-Df(x)) = I-Df(a)^{-1} Df(x)
\end{align}